# Save and add data in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I want new data to be added every time I click the save data button and the previous data will not be changed or deleted.

**I want the storage to be done on the internal memory**
**java**

[result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8JZo.png)

I will be happy for your help
Good luck

Comment: You need to use a database, you can use ROOM library for this. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Comment: If you don't want your data to persist across app sessions, you can simply use a list of object to store your data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.